# How to check if sbt in test context?

Tags: scala, testing, sbt

How can an application tell if it's running under an 'sbt test' context? Is there a system property that can be checked?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are probably different ways. I found the following works:

```
testOptions += Tests.Setup(_ => sys.props("testing") = "true")
```

And then you can just test for `sys.props.get("testing")` in your class.